# How to retrieve records from db where a particular column is equal to a set of Strings?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate

I have a table T1 with columns ID(primary key,varchar), name(varchar), value(number) and key(number).I have a String array which consists of ID's and I want to retrieve all the records with those id in the String array from TABLE T1 in a **single query**. How can I write this query in oracle?

I'm currently using a for loop and getting the records:

```
for(String id: idList)
{
   //Query to get record one by one (Select * from t1 where ID='id')
}
```

Could you suggest me a query to retrieve all these values in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query

```
select * from t1 where id in ('id1', 'id2', 'id3')
```

To get the ArrayList into the format, do the following

```
StringBuilder sb = New StringBuilder();
for(String id: idList)
{
   sb.append("'"+id+"',")
}
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() -1);
sb.toString();
```

Comment: The problem is that all the ids are in an arraylist of String. How do I put it in the form ('id1', 'id2', 'id3')?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Prep the query string
//---------------------------------

    $strQ ="";
    $len = count($idList);

    $strQ = "'".$idList[0]."'";

    for($i=1; $i<$len; $i++){
       $strQ += " or ID = '".$idList[$i]."'";
    }

//Now Da Query
//---------------------------------------

"Select * from t1 where ID= ".$strQ;

//---------------------
```

I've explained da above using PHP...

Comment: Could you add comments to your code so I can understand the logic as I dont know PHP and I'm currently using Java, it would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<Long> itemIDs = new ArrayList<Long>();
```

itemIDs.add(10);
....
....
AuthService.deletePracticeAppMenu(itemIDs, selectedPractice.getID());

---

```
public void deletePracticeAppMenu(List<Long> prAppMenuIDs, Long practiceID) {
    String query = "delete from PracticeAppMenu where PrAppMenuID  in (:appMenuIDs) and practiceID = :pracid ";
    Query q = getCurrentSession().createQuery(query);
    q.setParameterList("appMenuIDs", prAppMenuIDs);
    q.setParameter("pracid", practiceID);
    q.executeUpdate();
}
```